# Javascript Dropdown Selection Problem When Clicking Arrow

Tags: javascript, drop-down-menu, onclicklistener

I have a dropdown menu set up and populate it via Javascript. The HTML is simple:

```
      <select id="requesterList">
      </select>
```

I populate the dropdown list thus:

```
select=document.getElementById("requesterList");
for (let item of reqList.results) {
   var opt=item.requester_name;
   var el=document.createElement("option");
   el.textContent=opt;
   el.value=opt;
   select.appendChild(el);
}
```

I handle selections with a listener:

```
document.getElementById("requesterList").addEventListener("click",getreq);
```

This is the handler:

```
function getreq() {
   selection_obj=document.querySelector("#requesterList");
   console.log(selection_obj.value);
}
```

The problem is that when the arrow on the dropdown is clicked it triggers the function and selects the first item. How do I set this up so only the actual menu item triggers the function? TIA.

Comment: Use a `change` handler -- `....addEventListener("change",...`

Comment: Great, exactly what I wanted. Thanks.